# ¿Cómo crear columna derivada tipo fecha en SSIS para almacenarla en campo tipo date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

¿Cómo creo una columna derivada en base a 3 enteros para formar una fecha de la siguiente forma

```
10 entero 1
5  entero 2
2022 entero 3
```

unido que quede en un date así: `2022-5-10` , o así, `10-5-2022` para almacenar en un campo tipo date en sqlserver?

`(DT_DBDATE)("01" + "-" + CN_MES + "-" + CN_ANIO)` Tengo esto pero siempre me falla, no sé cuál es el error; `cn_mes` y `cn_anio` son enteros pero son dos columnas.

es SQL SERVER INTEGRATION SERVICES

Comment: Buenas, prueba con covert y concat, son dos funciones de sql-server

Comment: quieres una tabla con 3 columnas? o ya tienes la columna y quieres pasarla a fecha?

Comment: tengo una tabla con 2 columnas tipo int que tienen año y mes, lo que debo hacer es concatenar 01 a cada año y mes por ejemplo , 01-05-2022 pero en una columna derivada y luego en la tabla el campo tipo fecha tomara el valor de lo anterior

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en los comentarios, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- He recreado la tabla:

```sql
create table tablota(anio int, mes int)
insert into tablota values(2022, 10), (2022,11)
```

Así sería la tabla:

```sql
+------+-----+
| anio | mes | 
+------+-----+
| 2022 | 10  |
| 2022 | 11  |
+------+-----+
```

- Con base en la estructura anterior (toca adaptarla a la estructura que tenga tu tabla realmente):

```sql
select anio, 
       mes, 
       convert(date,concat('01-',mes,'-',anio), 103) fecha
from tablota
```

El resultado saldrá así:

```sql
+------+-----+------------+
| anio | mes | fecha      |
+------+-----+------------+
| 2022 | 10  | 2022-10-01 |
| 2022 | 11  | 2022-11-01 |
+------+-----+------------+
```

Comment: SI PERO REQUIERO HACERLO EN INTEGRATION SERVICES CON UNA COLUMNA DERIVADA NO DESDE SQL SERVER en sql server solo devo tener la definicion de la tabla con el campo fecha con valores nulos, los cuales tomaran el valor de la columna derivada en integration services

Comment: si solo necesito la columna derivada que concatene esos tres valores y los guarde en la columna destino tengo esto: (DT_DBDATE)("01" + "-" + CN_MES + "-" + CN_ANIO) pero siempre me da error de conexion, el campo de la tabla es tipo date

Comment: Qué error de conexión? Yo recuerdo que en un paso del ETL con SSIS se puede colocar un script SQL para trabajarlo tal cual fuera una consulta, no sé si a eso te estás refiriendo con ese (DT_DBDATE)(...)

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que te falta convertir tus columnas de enteros en cadenas. Dejo un ejemplo usando variables, pero deberías poder cambiarlo a columnas sin problemas.

```
 (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)((DT_WSTR, 4 )@[User::CN_ANIO]+"-"+(DT_WSTR, 4 )@[User::CN_MES]+"-01")
```

Comment: con est dt_dbtimestamp que tipo de dato deberia ser en la tabla de la base de datos para que no de inconveniente en el destino